# User defined function returns unexpected result

Tags: r, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

This is my first question on stackoverflow.com!

I have created the following functions to check for the existence of and remove a table in my PostgreSQL database, both before and after removal. Unfortunately, the removal function doesn't give me the expected output. When I evaluate `psql.exists.boolean(x,y)` with my inputs, it returns the expected result of TRUE, but when I evaluate `psql.drop(x,y)` with the same inputs, it doesn't return the expected result. Please provide me with some guidance for fixing my erroneous function.

```
psql.drop<-function(x,y){
table.bad<-x
dbschema<-y
db.location <- c(y,x)
if (psql.exists.boolean(y,x)==TRUE){
  dbRemoveTable(con,db.location)
    if (psql.exists.boolean(y,x)==TRUE){
      msg<-paste("ERROR! The table",dQuote(paste(db.location, collapse = '.')),"still exists!")
  } else if (psql.exists.boolean(y,x)==FALSE){
      msg<-paste("The table",dQuote(paste(db.location, collapse = '.')),"was successfully removed.")
  } else {
     msg<-paste("ERROR! Something went wrong.")
  }
} else {
  msg<-paste("The table",dQuote(paste(db.location, collapse = '.')),"doesn't exist.")
}
return(print(msg))

psql.drop("test_table_1","test_schema_1")
```

and

```
psql.exists.boolean<-function(x,y){
  # table name to check
  table.name<-x
  # schema where table is stored
  dbschema<-y
  # name format in schema  
  db.location <- c(dbschema, table.name)
  # check if table existence in specified location is true
  if(dbExistsTable(con,db.location)==TRUE){
    return(TRUE)
  }else{
    return(FALSE)
  }
}

psql.exists.boolean("test_table_1","test_schema_1")
```

Comment: What is the expected result for psql.drop(x,y)  and what are you getting when you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function psql.exists.boolean takes as input first the table name, then the schema name.
But when you call it within psql.drop, you give it first the schema name, then the table name (psql.exists.boolean(y,x)).